# "Controller ..CategoryController has required constructor arguments and does not exist in the container. Did you forget to define such a service?",

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm having trouble with a custom controller with Symfony4 and API Platform.

> {   "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",   "@type": "hydra:Error",
>   "hydra:title": "An error occurred",   "hydra:description": "Controller
>   \"\App\Controller\CategoryController\" has required constructor
>   arguments and does not exist in the container. Did you forget to
>   define such a service?",   "trace": [
>       {
>         "namespace": "",
>         "short_class": "",
>         "class": "",
>         "type": "",
>         "function": "",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver.php",
>         "line": 62,
>         "args": []
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller",
>         "short_class": "ContainerControllerResolver",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "instantiateController",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Controller\ControllerResolver.php",
>         "line": 54,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "string",
>             "\App\Controller\CategoryController"
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller",
>         "short_class": "ControllerResolver",
>         "class": "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "instantiateController",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php",
>         "line": 110,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "string",
>             "\App\Controller\CategoryController"
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller",
>         "short_class": "ControllerResolver",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "createController",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver.php",
>         "line": 42,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "string",
>             "\App\Controller\CategoryController::show"
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller",
>         "short_class": "ContainerControllerResolver",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "createController",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Controller\ControllerResolver.php",
>         "line": 46,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "string",
>             "\App\Controller\CategoryController::show"
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller",
>         "short_class": "ControllerResolver",
>         "class": "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "createController",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php",
>         "line": 85,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "string",
>             "\App\Controller\CategoryController::show"
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller",
>         "short_class": "ControllerResolver",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "getController",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver.php",
>         "line": 38,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "object",
>             "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller",
>         "short_class": "TraceableControllerResolver",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "getController",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php",
>         "line": 134,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "object",
>             "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel",
>         "short_class": "HttpKernel",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "handleRaw",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php",
>         "line": 68,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "object",
>             "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"
>           ],
>           [
>             "integer",
>             1
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel",
>         "short_class": "HttpKernel",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "handle",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php",
>         "line": 198,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "object",
>             "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"
>           ],
>           [
>             "integer",
>             1
>           ],
>           [
>             "boolean",
>             true
>           ]
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "namespace": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel",
>         "short_class": "Kernel",
>         "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel",
>         "type": "->",
>         "function": "handle",
>         "file": "C:\Users\Jonny\Desktop\Workspace\php\documentarywire\public\index.php",
>         "line": 25,
>         "args": [
>           [
>             "object",
>             "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request"
>           ]
>         ]
>       }   ] }

.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Service\CategoryService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class CategoryController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var CategoryService
     */
    private $categoryService;

    /**
     * @param CategoryService $categoryService
     */
    public function __construct(CategoryService $categoryService)
    {
        $this->categoryService = $categoryService;
    }

    public function show($slug)
    {
        return $slug;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the controller and service to services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    category_service:
        class: App\Service\CategoryService
        public: true

    App\Controller\CategoryController:
        arguments: ['@category_service']
```

Comment: Comment out the category_service and the CategoryController portions of your services.yaml file.  Neither of those entries are needed with autowire.  And see what sort of error messages (if any) you get.

Comment: @Cerad same error

Comment: Seems unlikely.  Search your code for CategoryController and verify that you don't have extra backslashes.

Comment: You can also use "bin/console debug:autowiring --all App" to see what services are defined.